# Angular - How to write test true or false in jasmin - Error Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type Expected<void>

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a simple function return true or false as in below. I'm getting `Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<void>'`. Where I made mistake?

app.ts

```
  onFocus(value: string) {
    if (value) {
      this.Showtimeline = true;
    } else {
      this.Showtimeline = false;
    }
  }
```

app.spec.ts

```
it('should return true when focus on input', () => {
    const value = component.Showtimeline = true;
    const result = component.onFocus(value);
    expect(result).toBe(true);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to test function. Like calling a function with a parameter update your showtimeline property so you need to check that property is updated or not.

```
it('should return true when focus on input', () => {
     component.onFocus(true);        
    expect(component.Showtimeline).toBe(true);
 });
```

and for false one

```
it('should return false when focus out input', () => {
     component.onFocus(false);        
    expect(component.Showtimeline).toBe(false);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some fundamental issue.
property `Showtimeline` is *boolean* so basically below code is assigning baoolean to **value**

```
const value = component.Showtimeline = true;
```

And `onFocus` expects to have a parameter of type *string*.

So two test cases can be:

```
it('should return true when focus on input', () => {
    const value = 'true';
    component.onFocus(value);
    expect(component.Showtimeline).toBe(true);
  });

it('should return falsewhen focus on input', () => {
    const value = '';
    component.onFocus(value);
    expect(component.Showtimeline).toBe(false);
  });
```

Comment: Thank u for notifying me. But im still getting ` Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<void>'. Is that should be `expect(result).toBeTruthy();`?

Comment: my bad, updating above post, this is because onFocus doesnt return anything, we will have to check Showtimeline  property

Comment: onFocus() doesnt return anything, instead it sets showtimeline property based on 'value' parameter received. So when we try to get return value from this statement -  const result = component.onFocus(value); and expect 'result' to be of some value, it throws error